# MySQL match existence of a term amongst Comma Seperated Values using REGEXP

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I have a MySQL select statement dilemma that has thrown me off course a little. In a certain column I have a category term. This term could look something like '**category**' or it could contain multiple CSV's, like this: '**category, bank special**'.

I need to retrieve all rows containing the term 'bank special' in the comma separated value. Currently, I am using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tblnecklaces WHERE nsubcat REGEXP 'bank special';
```

Now this works OK, but if I had the category as follows: **'diamond special'** for example, then the row is still retrieved because the term '**special**' in my column seems to be matching up to the term '**bank special**' in my REGEXP statement.

How would I go about checking for the existence of the whole phrase '**bank special**' only and not partially matching the words?

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the `LIKE` clause (`%` is wildcard):

```
SELECT * FROM tblnecklaces WHERE nsubcat LIKE '%bank special%';
```

Note that `LIKE` is also a lot faster than `REGEXP`.

Comment: And will that check for the existence of ONLY 'bank special' and not 'bank' OR 'special'?

Comment: @webfac: This searches for exact matches for _"bank special"_ (including space), and does not care what is in front or behind (thanks to the wildcard). _"bank"_ and _"special"_ are not going to match.

Comment: thank you so much for your efforts, your solution is simple, lightweight and effective in my situation. Have yourself a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix the column with comma's, and compare it to the bank special:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    tblnecklaces
WHERE   ',' + replace(nsubcat,', ','') + ',' LIKE ',bank special,'
```

I put in a replace to remove optional space after a comma, because your example has one.

Comment: While I appreciate your help, the above seems like a very intense solution to a not so complex problem. Elusives answer seems to be a little easier to digest. Thank you anyway

Comment: @webfac: The extra code is there so it works if you have both `special` and `back special` as a category.  With a simple `like`, both would match `special`.  If that kind of complexity is not needed, you're better off with the simple answer :)

Comment: I disagree, with the answer Elusive gave, if I add the wildcard at the end it checks for ONLY what is in between the wild cards and not either or, so %my check% will no check for 'my' OR 'check' but ONLY 'my check'

Comment: @webfac: but `%special%` would match `bank special`, and `bank special,super special,mega special`

Comment: Correct yes, but I need a simple match of 'bank special' against 'bank special' so I need not worry of a conflict in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but this RegExp should work (`LIKE` works too but will match items that starts or ends with the same phrase):

```
SELECT * FROM tblnecklaces WHERE nsubcat REGEXP '(^|, )bank special($|,)';
```